# Angular 7 - Reactive Form update modelo

Tags: angular

Tenho as seguintes classe no meu modelo

```js
export class TelefoneNumero {
    id: number;
    numero: string;
    descricao: string;
}
```

```js
export class Pessoa {

    constructor(){
        this.telefones = [];
    }
    
    id: number;
    nome: string;
    dataNascimento: string;
    telefones: TelefoneNumero[];
}
```

Tenho um componente de cadastro de pessoa e um componente para cadastro de telefone..

Dentro do meu componente de cadastro de pessoa eu incorporo o componente de telefone exemplo

cadastro-pessoa.component.ts

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-form-usuario',
    templateUrl: './form-usuario.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./form-usuario.component.scss']
})
export class FormUsuarioComponent implements OnInit {
  
  public pessoa: Pessoa;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.pessoa = new Pessoa()
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 pb-3">
    <label for="usuario.telefone">E-mail</label>
    <input formControlName="telefone" id="pessoa.telefone" class="form-control"/>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 pb-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h1 class="bd-title float-left">Telefones</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="card border-none">
      <div class="card-body pt-4">
        <app-telefone-form [telefones]="pessoa.telefones"></app-telefone-form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

cadastro-telefone.component.ts

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-telefone-form',
    templateUrl: './telefone-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./telefone-form.component.scss']
})
export class telefoneFormComponent implements OnInit {
  
  @Input() telefones: TelefoneNumero[];
  public telefoneForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

        this.telefoneForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            telefones: this.formBuilder.array([])
        });
    }

  addTelefone(): void {
        let telefones = <FormArray>this.telefoneForm.get('telefones');
        telefones.push(this.criarTelefone());
        this.telefoneForm.markAsDirty();
    }

  private criartelefone(): FormGroup {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
            numero: [null, [Validators.required]],
            descricao: [null, [Validators.required]]
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover" [formGroup]="telefoneForm">
  <tbody formArrayName="telefones">
    <tr *ngFor="let telefone of telefoneForm.get('telefones')['controls']; index as i" [formGroupName]="i">
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" (click)="addTelefone()">
                    <i class="icon-plus"></i>
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                
              <input formControlName="numero" type="text" class="form-control" />
<input formControlName="descricao" type="text" class="form-control" />
            </td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

o botão para salvar a pessoa está no componente da pessoa, mas os telefones estão no componente do telefone, como eu posso obter a lista de telefones ao clicar em um botão no componente da pessoa ( componente pai )

---

e é possível eu passar minha classe para o formBuilder? ou sempre vou ter que criar as propriedades no formbuilder (ex. numero e descrição do telefone), pois para fazer a operação inversa (popular minha classe com os dados do form builder) terei que rodar todos os campos do formBuilder e setar os valores na classe TelefoneNumero?

Exemplo

```js
onSubmit(){
  this.telefone.numero = this.telefoneForm.get('numero').value;
  this.telefone.descricao = this.telefoneForm.get('numero').descricao;
}
```

não teria uma forma automatica de espelhar a classe no formBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

Para criar o Form o jeito que vc está fazendo está certo.

Pra pegar o valor do form vc pode usar o spread operator do es6.

```
onSubmit(){
  this.telefone= {...this.telefoneForm.value, ...this.telefone};
}
```

Comment: mas eu teria que recriar todo o objeto do meu Model (TelefoneNumero) dentro do FormGroup né? digo declarar todos os atributos, seus sub-grupos caso fosse um objeto mais complexo, o FormBuilder ou FormGroup não aceita uma classe como parâmetro para criar os atributos para evitar esse retrabalho? e sobre a 1º questão de acessa o formbuilder do componente filho pelo pai a melhor opção seria através do @ViewChild?

Answer (score 0):

Ja tentou usar os EventEmitter?
Uma saida seria usar o event EventEmitter numa function do component filho e mandar para o pai.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar apenas um formGroup com todas as propriedades da pessoa, assim como os telefones, então basta passar esse formGroup via Input para o component `app-telefone-form`, assim você tem acesso a todas as informações do formulário em ambos os components, basta usar a API para pegar os valores, por exemplo o metodo .`getRawValue()` onde ele pega os valores atuais do formulário, ou seja, da pessoa.

Aqui vai uma leitura sobre a solução caso: https://medium.com/@joshblf/using-child-components-in-angular-forms-d44e60036664